# Can't Find make in MinGW

Tags: c++, netbeans, makefile, mingw

I'm using [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/) version of MinGW. I just installed this and Netbeans 7.4. I've added the bin folder to the Path variable, and when setting up the tool collection in Netbeans, it detected everything automatically except for "make". I've tried to find "make", but to no avail. Where is it located?

Thanks, Nic

Here are some screenshots:

Trying to add mingw32-make:
[image]

Running using make.exe:
[image]

Using NetBeans' suggestion:
[image]

Comment: Did you try `mingw32-make` ?

Comment: Yes, but Netbeans is highlighting it in red and not accepting it.

Comment: Does `make` or `mingw32-make` work if you invoke it directly from command-line ? (it may not be in your path)

Comment: I tried to download make.exe from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MSYS/Base/make/make-3.81-3/) but now NetBeans is giving me "The application failed with exit code -1073741515 (0xc0000135). This could indicate that no required .dll was found in the PATH."

Comment: Ah, it looks like it's not in the path. I thought it would be added just by adding the bin folder to path. How do I add mingw32-make?

Answer (score 0):

Netbean does not support Ming32-make, you need to use msys make.

please see https://netbeans.org/community/releases/72/cpp-setup-instructions.html for instruction on how to install msys

Answer (score -1):

Go to `Control Panel > System and security > System > Advanced system settings > Environment variables`. Edit the `PATH` variable and append `;X:\PATH\OF\MINGW\bin` and you should have `mingw32-make` in your path.

Comment: Well that isn't the problem. That's what I already had in my path variable. When I use make, NetBeans mentions a dll, but it won't accept mingw32-make at all.

Comment: Could you please show some screenshots to help understand the problem ?

Comment: Added some screenshots.

Comment: Can you try to launch it in your project working directory, where the `Makefile` is located ?

Comment: Didn't work either. I'm just going to install standard MinGW. Thanks for the help anyways.